# Posting to GooglePlus in php using google/google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I am wondering is it currently possible to post to google plus from website(using php), I read sometime back that the google plus api is for readonly, then i met this  [Post to Google Plus Wall(activities) #1195](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1195)

the documentation of the package does not give a clear example for that [google/google-api-php-client on github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
 , can someone please clarify on this and possibly provide a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general the Google+ API is read-only. Specifically though paid G Suite users can post private content accessible to other users of that G Suite domain.

Comment: Thanks @abraham, does the google+ api allow to post to google+ business pages? or do i still the G suite for that capability.

Comment: You might be able to post to a G Suite controlled page via the Domains API.  I haven't tested it. Traditionally there was a Pages API that Google enabled for a select few partners.